# My downloads are at 0% need help interpreting error in logs

Tags: sccm

DataTansferService.log:

```
Successfully queued event on HTTP/HTTPS failure for server 'ADB-ITS-02.ad.mydomain.com'.
Error sending DAV request. HTTP code 0, status ''
Download timeout has met. DTS job {95D7ABBA-59BD-46B1-BD33-6C1661A8FEDF} will quit.
GetDirectoryList_HTTP('https://ADB-ITS-02.ad.mydomain.com:443/CCMTOKENAUTH_SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/Content_cb286a91-80a3-41fd-8a61-81ca0a50fdd5.1') failed with code 0x800705b4.
Error retrieving manifest (0x800705b4).
```

Answer (score 0):

By googling the error code I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/3a1691/0x800705b4_software_updates_failing_during_osd/) thread on reddit which might help you.

**Edit:**
Also http_code 0 tells me that it is probably not able to connect to the server at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a SCCM client or the SCCM/MECM server that's doing the download?

Check proxy settings:

1. "Internet Settings" in Control Panel
2. WINHTTP from the command line (as admin): `netsh winhttp show proxy`
3. If SCCM Server, check the proxy settings in the Administrator> Settings section

You'll either need to configure a proxy, depending on your network requirements, update it's configuration, or remove the configuration.